# desktop notification using socket.io icon not displaying

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have included desktop notification in my project. Along with notification an icon should be displayed. My code seems to be correct.But the icon is not displayed in the notification.

if i am adding the complete URL like 'www.site.com/image/not.png' it may display in chrome , but not in firefox .

**Here is the code**

```
var options = {
      body: 'Test Notification',
      icon: "not.png",
      dir : "ltr"
};
```

How can I get the icon to display properly within the notification?

Comment: try using iconUrl instead of icon